# How to make Ansible Jinja2 lookup loop a list?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, I am trying to get the first defined value from a list of environment variables: `BUILD_USER_EMAIL`, `GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL`, `GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`, `GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_EMAIL`

The code for getting one looks like

```
- email: "{{ lookup('env', 'BUILD_USER_EMAIL')}}"
```

When the variable is not defined this this resolves to empty string which is ok.

Now the question is how to do implement this as loop of fallbacks so I would try to find the first defined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>An answer improved based on [OP’s own research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48122067/2947502).</sup>

```
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ envcandidates | reject('equalto', '') | first }}"
    vars:
      envcandidates: “{{ lookup('env', 'BUILD_USER_EMAIL', 'GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL', 'GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL', 'GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL', wantlist=True) }}”
```

You might want to add `| default` filter if you don't want it to fail if neither of the variables were set, or just add a default value to the end of `envcandidates` list.

Comment: Nice one! I guess you could simplify with a simple `| select | list` as select doc says "If no test is specified, each object will be evaluated as a boolean." and empty strings are evaluated as False and so won't be selected; but it less explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I can see this as a solution:

```
- email: "{{ lookup('env', 'BUILD_USER_EMAIL') |
             default(lookup('env', 'GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL'), True) |
             default(lookup('env', 'GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL'), True) |
             default(lookup('env', 'GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_EMAIL'), True) |
             default('UNDEFINED', True) }}"
```

The `True` are here to force jinja2 to evaluate empty string as None.